# How can I run two different Access database macros concurrently?

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

The script below works but how can I get the script to run both databases' macros at the same time?

```
set oaccess1 = createobject("access.application")
oaccess1.opencurrentdatabase "C:\support_db3_created.accdb"
set oaccess2 = createobject("access.application")
oaccess2.opencurrentdatabase "p:\public\ryan simmons\access\support_db4_completed.accdb"
oaccess1.docmd.runmacro "runmacro"
oaccess2.docmd.runmacro "runmacro"
oaccess1.closecurrentdatabase
oaccess2.closecurrentdatabase
oaccess1.quit
oaccess2.quit
set oaccess1=nothing
set oaccess2=nothing

x=msgbox("Script Completed!" ,0, "Alert!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. VBScript doesn't allow concurrency inside a script. You need to run two scripts if you need parallel execution. If required you can use files or registry values to synchronize the two scripts:

Script A:

```
'do stuff

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\test\syncpoint", 1, "REG_DWORD"

'do other stuff
```

Script B:

```
Const HKCU = &h80000001
Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

'do stuff

'wait for script A to create the registry value
Do
  rc = reg.GetDWORDValue(HKCU, "Software\test", "syncpoint", v)
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop Until rc = 0 And Not IsNull(v)

'do other stuff
```

Comment: So after some testing yesterday this works great. I run Script B first which sits and waits for the registry to be changed. I also run Script A which runs my databases through a couple of phases. When Script A reaches the final phase where two databases need to be run concurrently it changes the registry value and Script B runs it's database. The only change I made is I added a line to Script A sh.RegDelete "HKCU\Software\test\syncpoint" so that it changes the registry back so that the process can be repeated.